# Netstat -ban (or -oan) equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, netstat

I'd like to know if a particular process is using a given port, i.e. `netstat -ban`. I came across using `IPGlobalProperties` to get the list of active connections, but this doesn't seem to include process information.

It would be nice if there exists some class in C# that lets me do this programmatically. Ideally, I wouldn't have to pipe the cmd shell `Process` output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this question...

[Which PID listens on a given port in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c)

Basically you PInvoke [GetExtendedTcpTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Oops! I didn't come across this thread in my search. Thanks, and sorry for the dup.