# Is there any alternative for netstat command in C#?

Tags: c#, netstat

I am writing a C# program which tells the Active Connections (Protocal, Local Address , Foreign Address , State , Process Id ) . To do this I am running cmd.exe as a process and passing netstat -ano as an argument.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","netstat -ano");
```

This returns Active connections .
But I don't want to use this netstat command .

Is there any alternative for netstat.exe in C# ?
Any library or something else so that I can get the same output ?

Comment: I'll never understand using cmd.exe to launch netstat.exe rather than just launching netstat.exe.

Comment: I am unable to launch netstat.exe directly that is why I am using cmd.exe for that

Comment: Why are you unable to launch netstat.exe directly? They're both in system32, which is in the PATH variable, so you should be able to launch netstat.exe just as easily as cmd.exe.

Comment: I have messed up the environment variables

Comment: Then how are you able to launch cmd.exe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netstat -ban (or -oan) equivalent in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775648/netstat-ban-or-oan-equivalent-in-net)

Comment: You'll likely have to find something to [P/Invoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to run nmap or netstat, you can get all the info much easier when you take a look at the ***System.Net.NetworkInformation*** namespace. There you can find charming things like `GetActiveTcpListeners()` or `GetActiveTcpConnections()` and much more.

```
public static void ShowActiveTcpConnections()
{
           Console.WriteLine("Active TCP Connections");
           IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
           TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
           foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("{0} <==> {1}",
                   c.LocalEndPoint.ToString(),
                   c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
           }
}
```

Details are here in the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections?view=net-5.0

Comment: Process id is not being shown there. Is there any way to get the process id also ? By the way thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an `netstat` alternative as you and I found [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/).

To scan I usually run:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.*
```

Comment: How can I get the process id ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c-sharp