# Finding listening services on TCP UDP ports using C#

Tags: c#, service, tcp, udp, port

Is there a way of finding which services are listening at a particular port (TCP/UDP)
using C# libraries?

Comment: C# is a language. .NET is a framework (among other things a collection of libraries).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which PID listens on a given port in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c)