# How can I filter GetActiveTcpConnections to only include those for a particular image name?

Tags: c#

How I get all tcp connections from a specific app?

I have all connections, it is ok but I need to determine process Id or appName or Image (is named on Windows resource monitoring network tab).

Currently I have this:

```
var properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
var connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections().Where(I need here).ToList();
```

But I'm not sure what to use in the `Where()` linq statement?

[image: ResourceMonitor]

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which PID listens on a given port in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c-sharp)