# How to scan emphreal ports?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if, this is the right way to scan empheral ports.
Basically I'm getting my IPv4 and then adding port by port from 49125 up to 65536.

```
class FreeTcpPort
    {
        public static IPAddress GetFirstIPv4Address(string hostname)
        {
            return Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname)
                .Where(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) // InterNetwork == IPv4 !!!
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public int GetFreeTcpPort()
        {
            Socket testSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(GetFirstIPv4Address(String.Empty), 1024);
            for (int i = 65535; i > 49125; i--)
            {
                try
                {
                    endPoint.Port = i;
                    testSocket.Connect(endPoint);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                }
                testSocket.Close();
                testSocket.Dispose();
                return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Why I'm asking ?

Because I'm getting that the most ports are closed, to be more precised it says that, the connection couldn't be established, which is not true because most of those ports are open. Only arond 30 are closed/not free.

Comment: When you sasy "open", do you mean "listening", or...? You can only connect to ports where there is an application listening, and only if the listening application accepts the connection.

Comment: I want to check if they are open

Comment: [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c-sharp) has a PInvoke wrapper for GetExtendedTcpTable you could read the ports in use from instead.